# Perl WordNet::Similarity installation issue

Tags: perl, similarity

I have tried with ActiveState and Strawberry but I get the same error message every time I run

```
cpan install WordNet::Similarity
```

Shortend it down to this output:

```
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-Iblib\arch" "-Iblib\lib" build/Depthfiles.PL b
lib\lib/WordNet/synsetdepths.dat
Generating default depth files.
Loading WordNet::QueryData... done
Finding depths of noun taxonomies... (getSense) Internal error: offset=00002342
pos=n at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/WordNet/QueryData.pm line 633, <GEN8> line
1.
Compilation failed in require at build/Depthfiles.PL line 27, <GEN8> line 1.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'blib\lib\WordNet\synsetdepths.dat'
  TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.41)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'WordNet::Similarity'.
```

Earlier I had the problem that WordNet was missing some .dat files, but that I solved by the help of Ted Pedersen mail archive. But this one really got me stuck. Anyone have any idea?

UPDATE:

Okay, I'm working in Ubuntu now but now I got a different problem:

```
#   Failed test at t/trace.t line 141.
#          got: '4'
#     expected: '0'
# lesk: The lines 'Overlaps: 1 x "the"  1 x "small"  1 x "of"  2 x "any"  1 x "in the"  1 x "or"  1 x "resembling the"  1 x "and"  ' and 'Overlaps: 1 x "the"  1 x "small"  1 x "in the"  1 x "or"  1 x "of"  1 x "resembling the"  2 x "any"  1 x "and"  ' differ
t/trace.t ......... 107/132 # Looks like you failed 1 test of 132.
t/trace.t ......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/132 subtests 
t/vector.t ........ ok   
t/vector_pairs.t .. ok   
t/wn30loop.t ...... ok     
t/wup.t ........... ok     

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/trace.t       (Wstat: 256 Tests: 132 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  76
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=22, Tests=2027, 136 wallclock secs ( 0.68 usr  0.05 sys + 132.59 cusr  3.44 csys = 136.76 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/22 test programs. 1/2027 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Comment: Just an idea: maybe the module is missing some `binmode()` calls?

Comment: OK, I will check that out when I have some spare time. I guess you noticed but this is on windows (8.1), I have not tried to install this in Ubuntu. I might try that when I have some spare time aswell :)

Comment: That's why I suggest adding `binmode()` calls. It's highly probable that the offsets are off on the Windows machine, because of possible `\r\n -> \n` translations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual-looking error, but I wonder if in deleting things from WordNet you might have removed something additional? I don't work much with Windows but if you do have the option of running on Linux then I think things will go more smoothly. That said, I know it runs on Windows (have had positive reports from Strawberry and Active Perl).

So...about the only thing I can suggest is to try to reinstall WordNet on Windows, or if you can run on Linux consider doing that as I think that tends to be a fairly smooth install. I think it can be on Windows too, it's just less common I think.

Comment: I really think it's missing `binmode` calls. See one of my comments earlier.

Comment: With a clean install of WordNet 2.1, the installation is missing noun.dat. From the change log: wnDepths.pl had forgotten that on Windows some filenames are different; for example, data.noun is noun.dat. (JM)
Tried to copy these files and rename and put them in dict. Then the same error is back: Internal error: offset=00002342
I don't have any experience with Perl, so if someone would put me in the right direction for the binmode() I would appreciate that!

Comment: Updated the first post with the new error in Ubuntu. Got a little bit further this time :)