# Perl Ubuntu WordNet::SenseRelate::AllWords - Similarity issue during installation

Tags: perl, ubuntu, nlp, word-sense-disambiguation

if this is spamming the forum then I'm sorry, but I felt like creating a new thread for this issue since I'm now working in Ubuntu and not Windows (hurraay!). Link to old thread: [Perl WordNet::Similarity installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809532/perl-wordnetsimilarity-installation-issue)

This is the error I get now:

```
TPEDERSE/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/Error-Suffixes-tagged-wntagged.t .. Can't locate WordNet/Tools.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/lib /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/Error-Suffixes-tagged-wntagged.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/Error-Suffixes-tagged-wntagged.t line 6.
t/Error-Suffixes-tagged-wntagged.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords.t .... Can't locate WordNet/Tools.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/lib /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords.t line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords.t line 21.
t/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords.t .... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/wsd.t ............................. Can't locate WordNet/Tools.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/lib /home/kristian/.cpan/build/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19-VGDkgr/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/wsd.t line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/wsd.t line 24.
t/wsd.t ............................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/Error-Suffixes-tagged-wntagged.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords.t  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/wsd.t                           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=3, Tests=0,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.00 sys +  0.13 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 3/3 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  TPEDERSE/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (WordNet::Similarity); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TPEDERSE/WordNet-SenseRelate-AllWords-0.19.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

**UPD:** After installing missing module got this:

> Test Summary Report - t/trace.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 132 Failed: 1)
>   Failed test: 76 Non-zero exit status: 1 Files=22, Tests=2027, 88
>   wallclock secs ( 0.48 usr 0.05 sys + 85.34 cusr 2.23 csys = 88.10 CPU)
>   Result: FAIL Failed 1/22 test programs. 1/2027 subtests failed. make:
>   *** [test_dynamic] Error 255 TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK //hint// to see the cpan-testers results
>   for installing this module, try: reports
>   TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz Running make install make test
>   had returned bad status, won't install without force

Comment: Have you tried using the `apt-get` feature to install this module?

Comment: You seems to miss the WordNet::Tools package. Try installing it first.

Comment: @Davs Which is exactly why you use `apt-get` instead, because it takes care of dependencies and updating packages.

Comment: A good way to have your questions ignored is to post them and abandon them. You should be prepared to give feedback to the feedback you receive, not come back in 8 hours and see if anyone posted anything. Expect answers within minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I try to install WordNet::Tools now. Sorry if I'm not answering early enough, will try to improve on that!

Comment: @cloms You might also like the site askubuntu.com, which is a StackExchange site dedicated to Ubuntu.

Comment: OK. I just posted the result of running WordNet:Tools in the comments under, didn't want to double post the answer. Couldnt paste everything since there is a limit, but think I got the most relevant piece.

Comment: WordNet-Similarity tests fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. What's your configuration? However, I see the t/trace.t error on another system (see here http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/68fbd7f6-4719-11e3-8e85-2f09e1bfc7aa ).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. Anything else you need to know? It's a Sony Vaio for all that matters. Ok, I will try to find my own report, if it's autogenerated? I'll have a look, and I will try to check in for answers as often as I remember.

Comment: No errors on my Ubuntu 13.10 (desktop, 32 bit). I did: `sudo apt-get install libwordnet-querydata-perl && env WNSEARCHDIR=/usr/share/wordnet cpan -t WordNet::Similarity`. Maybe you should write a bug report to the WordNet::Similarity author?

Comment: I downloaded WordNet-3.0.tar.gz from their website and installed it.
What I have done now was ignore the Similarity test that fail, and did
    cpan force install WordNet::Similarity
and after that i forced install of SenseRelate::AllWords. Now I think it's installed.
Source: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86437

Answer (score 0):

As we can see `Can't locate WordNet/Tools.pm in @INC` firstly you should install WordNet::Tools then try again this installation.

Comment: Trying this solution now :) Will give feedback on how it goes!

Comment: Test Summary Report
-
t/trace.t       (Wstat: 256 Tests: 132 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  76
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=22, Tests=2027, 88 wallclock secs ( 0.48 usr  0.05 sys + 85.34 cusr  2.23 csys = 88.10 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/22 test programs. 1/2027 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force

Comment: Open file t/trace.t find 76th test and examine it. You will find some useful info into the test file.

Comment: In /cpan/build/wordnetSimilarity-t/trace.t ?
I can't find test 76 in any good way, don't know if this is the correct place. I will look somewhere else aswell